# $_POST not storing values after session restart

Tags: session, post

I'm using $_SESSION to store data from a multipage form.  When the form is complete and submitted, kill the session and erase session data:

```
$_SESSION = array();

setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000]

session_destroy();
```

I then call session_start() when I next serve up the form.

However, nothing is being stored in $_POST or $_SESSION after restarting the session.  I have tried switching browsers and restarting the server, both to no effect.

I'd really appreciate any ideas re. what might be up.

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: Instead of narrating your code, please show it.